# RecyclerView.Adapter ClassCastException when scrolling a lot

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, classcastexception

I am building a chat app, where i am using a RecyclerView with an adapter and it is using different viewholders, because the server sends Rich Content which require different views graphs etc.

When i am normally using the app and chat with the server, asking for different content which means different viewholders everything works fine. The Top level adapter is casting the main viewholder to the one i need every time i send a different request.

After a long chat and different viewholders generated and inflated, if i scroll fast, the RecyclerView, up and down, the main adapter is re-rendering the items and it will crash with a classcastException, in cases that earlier, while chatting, it didnt crash.

Here is an example:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

    //depending the type of rich content i get from the server i inflate the respective xml
    switch (MessageType.values()[viewType]) {
        case 1:
            View plainTextView = inflater....
            return new ViewHolder1(plainTextView);
        case 2:
            View secondView = inflater...
            return new ViewHolder2(secondView);
        case 3:
            View thirdView = inflater...
            return new ViewHolder3(verticalView);     
    }
   return null;
}
```

Then in the onBindViewHolder i cast the ViewHolder depending on the case of the onCreateViewHolder

```
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
                [...]
    case 2:

                    final ViewHolder2 holder = (ViewHolder2) holder;
                    //do stuff
                    break;
```

The error

```
2020-01-20 13:22:57.322 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.----.app, PID: 28353
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.-----.ui.adapters.MainCarouselAdapter$CarouselViewHolder cannot be cast to com.----.ui.adapters.QuickRepliesAdapter$OptionsViewHolder
    at com.-----.ui.adapters.QuickRepliesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(QuickRepliesAdapter.java:22)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:288)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchInnerRecyclerViewWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:335)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:351)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:361)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:368)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:399)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: final ViewHolder2 holder = (QuickRepliesViewHolder) holder; this line itself tells the error. You cannot pass the different class cast variable to any other class.

Comment: I am sorry, its a typo. Edited now

Comment: more code needed to answer, also post the logcat. There may also be some chances that your case is not matching  and it returns null at the time of onCreateViewHolder

Comment: @AnkushBist added the error. And no, im not trying to match null;

Comment: @AnkushBist, what i dont understand is why this error occurs only when im scrolling fast and not while chatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing something similar, i had a shared viewPool for my main and sub RecyclerViews.

> Recycled view pools allow multiple RecyclerViews to share a common pool of **scrape** views. This can be useful if you have multiple RecyclerViews with adapters that use the same view types, for example if you have several data sets with the same kinds of item views displayed by a ViewPager.

I dont have the same ViewTypes in my inflations so i found out that it had to leave.

When removing it the bug stopped existing. In addition i fixed my "naming" in the different xml files that where inflated depending the ViewHolder that would be called. I was using the same names for some common TextViews etc.

Comment: Actually I'm facing the same issue and I don't know why this is happening. If i scroll fast to up and down, the app crashes. Everything i checked, it looks fine but i ain't getting why this is happening. How did u fixed this issue ?